# Why am I getting conflicting results when document.getElementsByTagName is run from the console verses a script file?

Tags: javascript

Why is it that when I run:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText;
```

from the console, the inner text of the first p element is returned (correctly as the inner text of the p element), but when I run it via a script file from the browser the console logs it as 'undefined'?

here's the code I'm running from the internal .js file:

```
console.log('test', document.getElementsByTagName('p').innerText);
```

here's the console output: `test undefined`

Comment: You're not selecting the first element of the collection in your second example: the [0]

Comment: Another possibility is that the DOM changes after the initial call and you calling the `getElementByTagName` in the console.

Comment: @user184994 I had considered that, but the script file is right above the closing body tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.getElementsByTagName()` returns a node list. The following:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p').innerText
```

attempts to get the `.innerText` of that node list, but node lists don't have `.innerText`, only individual nodes do. You must access one of the nodes in the list and then you can get its `.innerText`, like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText
```

---

Also, at the time that you have the console open and are typing into it, the document has been fully parsed. Your same test, but with code in the file is being attempted prior to the `p` elements being parsed.

Make sure you have your `script` tag located just before the closing `body` tag in your document so that by the time it is encountered, all HTML will have been parsed into memory.

Examples:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Attempting to get DOM references too early</title>
  
  <script>
    // This will fail because, at this point, the <p> hasn't been parsed yet
    console.log(document.querySelector("p").textContent);
  </script>
  
</head>
<body>
  <p>Test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Getting DOM references after the DOM is ready</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Test</p>
  
  <script>
    // This will work because, at this point, the <p> has been parsed
    console.log(document.querySelector("p").textContent);
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

FYI:

- **[`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)** returns a "live" node list that can hinder page performance because every time the variable is
  accessed, the entire document must be searched again to ensure you
  have the most up-to-date collection. This is not appropriate in many
  use-cases (especially if your document isn't dynamically
  adding/removing elements). So, in most cases, use
  **[`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** instead, as this method returns a "static" node list.
- **[`.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText)** is a "de facto" standard, but it works differently than
  `.textContent`, which is an actual standard. Use **[`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)**
  instead.

Comment: Thank you! I did check that my javascript was right above the </body> and not executing before the <p> tag had loaded. My code has the p above the script include:   <p class="result">Please fill in all the fields</p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/tronCalc.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: @hanumanDev Refer to the first part of my answer. What you are testing in the console is a specific node's text and what you have in the code is trying to get the `.innerText` of an entire node list.